# How to add double quote on php echo

Tags: php, double, quote

Hey guys can someone tell me how to add double quote on `style=""` in order for my jquery to work.

PHP code - Didnt work

```
echo" <div class='fill' style='background-image:url('image/".$row["image"]."');'></div>";
```

HTML Code - This work

```
<div class='fill' style="background-image:url('image/img.jpg');"></div>
```

I know that I can add escape it using `\"` but I already tried that but its still didnt work.

Comment: Why don't the single quotes work? Why doesn't the escaping work? What happens in with your previous/current attempts?

Comment: Are you sure `$row["image"]` is what you think it is?  Take a look at the HTML your PHP is generating.

Comment: `I know that I can add escape it using \" but I already tried that but its still didnt work.`
Please elaborate. Share the escaped code, you most likely made a typo when escaping.

Comment: `echo "<div class='fill' style='background-image:url(\"image/".$row["image"]."\");'></div>";`

Comment: ^ would be an approach, but since we're already here, if you have already tried something, why don't you also post the tried code here?

Answer (score 0):

Either of these methods should work.  Effectively, you cannot use the same style quote inside the same style quote - so it must be escaped.

```
echo" <div class='fill' style='background-image:url(\'image/".$row["image"]."\');'></div>";

echo" <div class=\"fill\" style=\"background-image:url('image/".$row['image']."');\"></div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, for when you're dealing with strings that use both types of quotes, consider using a [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc):

```
echo <<<EOL
<a href="javascript:alert('hi mom!')">click me</a>
EOL;
```

No need to escape any of the quotes in this case.

Comment: I tried it doest work and Im guessing `".$row["image"]."` is my problem? I have no idea